# Syntax error when running Rails scaffolding on OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

When I am attempting to run a basic rails scaffolding I get the following error

```
invoke  active_record
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `load': syntax error on line 54, col 11: `' (ArgumentError)
```

I am guessing there is an encoding issue here, but not sure at all. When I try

```
echo $LC_CTYPE
```

I get

```
UTF-8
```

When I try

```
ruby -e 'puts Encoding.default_external.name'
```

I get

```
US-ASCII
```

Answer (score 0):

There is so much problems with syck.

Try installing ruby 1.9.2 from rvm, updating gems

```
gem update --system
```

and running it in new shell.